# I cannot make dataframe using streaming mode for online prediction in apache spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, streaming, spark-streaming

I am new in spark and I would like to make a streaming program. I need to predict a number repetition for each of my rows. Here is my raw data:

```
05:49:56.604899 00:00:00:00:00:02 > 00:00:00:00:00:03, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 10202: 10.0.0.2.54880 > 10.0.0.3.5001: Flags [.], seq 3641977583:3641987719, ack 129899328, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 432623 ecr 432619], length 10136
05:49:56.604908 00:00:00:00:00:03 > 00:00:00:00:00:02, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.0.0.3.5001 > 10.0.0.2.54880: Flags [.], ack 10136, win 153, options [nop,nop,TS val 432623 ecr 432623], length 0
05:49:56.604900 00:00:00:00:00:02 > 00:00:00:00:00:03, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 4410: 10.0.0.2.54880 > 10.0.0.3.5001: Flags [P.], seq 10136:14480, ack 1, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 432623 ecr 432619], length 4344
```

I wrote a code that extract my suitable output like below. (I needed the number of repetition on column1 and column2)

[image]

Here is my code:

However my code is not in a streaming mode. I did another code to obtain a streaming mode. Because the train.csv file is generating in streaming way. But I got some errors.
Here is my streaming code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.{LabeledPoint, StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

import scala.util.Try
/**
  * Created by saeedtkh on 5/24/17.
  */
object Main_ML_with_Streaming {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("saeed_test").setMaster("local[*]")
    //val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))


    /////////////////////Start extract the packet
    val customSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("column0", StringType, true),
      StructField("column1", StringType, true),
      StructField("column2", StringType, true)))


    val rdd = ssc.textFileStream("/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/train.csv")
    val rowRdd =rdd.map(line => line.split(">")).map(array => {
      val first = Try(array(0).trim.split(" ")(0)) getOrElse ""
      val second = Try(array(1).trim.split(" ")(6)) getOrElse ""
      val third = Try(array(2).trim.split(" ")(0).replace(":", "")) getOrElse ""
      Row.fromSeq(Seq(first, second, third))
    })

    val dataFrame_trainingData = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, customSchema)
    dataFrame_trainingData.groupBy("column1","column2").count().show()

    /////////////////////end extract the packet

    val testData = ssc.textFileStream(/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/test.csv).map(LabeledPoint.parse)
    ////////////////////end trainging and testing

    val numFeatures = 3
    val model = new StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD()
      .setInitialWeights(Vectors.zeros(numFeatures))

    model.trainOn(dataFrame_trainingData)
    model.predictOnValues(testData.map(lp => (lp.label, lp.features))).print()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()

    print("Here is the anwser: *****########*********#########*******222")
  }
}
```

The problem is that, I can not create a dataframe using sqlcontext in this line in my code:

```
val dataFrame_trainingData = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, customSchema)
```

Can any body help me to modify this code that works in streaming way and predicts repetition of each row using Linear Regression or any other algorithm. Thanks a lot.

**Update1:**
Acoording to answer number one, I added foreach but errors are still exists:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's important to note that `ssc.textFileStream` returns a [`DStream`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream) and not an `RDD`, so the variables you named `rdd`, `rowRdd` and `testData` are not really RDDs, but rather abstractions over a continuous sequence of RDDs. Therefore, you cannot pass these to `createDataFrame` which expects RDDs.

You can create a DataFrame out of each underlying RDD using `DStream.foreachRDD`, as described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations):

```
rowRdd.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val dataFrame_trainingData = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, customSchema)
  // ...
}
```

However, you should notice that [`StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD) expects DStreams as inputs for `trainOn` and `predictOnValues` - so you can simply pass the original DStreams without converting them into DataFrames.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added a foreach, but errors are still exists. I have updated the question and you can see the errors in update1.

Comment: Since I need to executes some queries in future, I used a data frame. But I have question, as you said, can I used first and second parameter directly in predictonvalues()?

Comment: If you're going for the `foreachRDD` approach (which, as I wrote, does NOT seem like the best approach in your case given how `StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD` works) - you should perform your entire calculation within the function supplied to `foreachRDD` - not outside of it (i.e. before the closing curly bracket `}`);

Comment: Even if I change the position of '}', the errors for SqlContext and groupby are still exist. :(

Comment: of course `sqlContext` produces an error, you didn't define it... add the definition similarly to how you did it before adding streaming. I won't answer more such comments - this isn't a debugging service and these further questions are outside the scope of the original question (which had to do with creating DataFrames from DStreams). Hope this helped, try reading the guides in the links I supplied to learn the streaming APIs, don't expect them to work exactly the same way as the non-streaming APIs.